# is it possible to do audio via DVI -> HDMI with Audigy Rx SPDIF to nvidia 8500 GT

Tags: hdmi, dvi, digital-audio, spdif

I currently have a setup with a Soundblaster audigy RX and a XFX Nvidia 8500 GT.
The particular graphics card I have does not have HDMI but ive seen posts saying it
is possible to send video and audio over a dvi->hdmi cable if you connect some spdif
pins. I am not sure exactly where to look for those pins.

This is the sound card
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829102063

and this is the graphics card
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150303

Comment: Do you want the audio to be channeled through the HDMI cable? Actually I had done it with 9800GT. My TV played the music via HDMI after setting the default audio device as the TV in my windows sound settings.

Comment: yea basically would like it to work the same way plugging a laptop into a TV would. Added not I am using Xubuntu with an XBMC setup

Comment: Check this link - http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=121168
To know where the SPDIF pins are check this - http://www.overclock.net/t/441176/guide-8800gt-9800gt-9800gtx-sound-over-hdmi-now-including-creative-cards